# How to detect if WinZip file is licensed or not using Java or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, winzip

I'm trying to design one tool using java which detects WinZip file is licensed or not.

I have tried this:

```java
File file = new File("C:/D/tst/myfile.zip");
isValidZip(file);

public static boolean isValidZip(File file) {
    ZipFile zipfile = null;
    try {
        zipfile = new ZipFile(file);
        System.out.println("valid");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid");
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it really does not validate the licensing of the file.

Do we have any Java Class using which we can verify if the file is licensed or not?

I want to detect following using java:

[Winzip Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HLKz.png)

Comment: 1. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour); 2. What does this has to do with JavaScript?

Comment: If we have any option to detect it using JavaScript? not sure if we have any such option. Thanks

Comment: I don't think anybody here knows exactly, but I would suggest you to compare some licensed files and some non-licensed in a hex editor or Notepad++. Then see what's changing between versions but the same in the same version.